# Navigator (overview) box in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm quite newbie to WPF and need some help. There is a Canvas in WPF containing figures, images, text and so on. I'd like to implement a box which contains preview of canvas' content and capable of panning and zooming. Something similar to this:
[image]

Any ideas how to implement this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Panning and zooming of what.. Canvas or Preview ?

Comment: It would be helpful if you attach an image relivant to the question

Comment: Yes, it's good idea. I've attached the picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the easiest way that you could do that would be to use the [`VisualBrush` Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visualbrush%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Basically, it just like any other `Brush`, so you could just paint a plain old `Rectangle` with it, but the important difference is that you can set whatever you like for its `Visual` property and that will appear in the `Rectangle`.

More than that, it is also live, so any changes that you make to whatever you used as the `Visual` will be updated in the painted `Rectangle`. It's been a while, but I'm pretty sure that it has a `ViewBox` which enables you to just show a part of the `Visual` as well.

Furthermore, as all (I think) of the UI controls extend the `Visual` class, that means that you can set any UI object as the `VisualBrush.Visual` property value. Please see the linked page for more information and code examples.

Comment: I guess it's exactly what I'm looking for. One more additional qiestion: if I use VisualBrush or Viewbox to display part of visual will it have to render it twice?

Comment: According to the linked page on MSDN, when you *Use an existing Visual, [it] creates a duplicate image of the target Visual*, so no it doesn't need to render twice. I would strongly advise you to read the Remarks section of that page as there are a couple of important things that you will need to know.